# How do I use a ruby regex to get a substring?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

I want to get the numbers out of strings such as:

`person_3

person_34

person_356

city_4

city_15`
etc...

It seems to me that the following should work:

`string[/[0-9]*/]`

but this always spits out an empty string.

Comment: string[/_.*$/][1..-1] works, but I'm still curious why just asking for the [0-9]* doesn't work...

Comment: ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[0-9]*` successfully matches "0 or more" digits at the beginning of the string, so it returns `""`. `[0-9]+` will match "1 or more" digits, and works as you expect:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = "test 92"
=> "test 92"
irb(main):003:0> x[/\d*/]
=> ""
irb(main):005:0> x.index(/\d*/)
=> 0
irb(main):004:0> x[/\d+/]
=> "92"
```

Comment: It's not because of non-greedy matching (which it isn't), but because `*` matches _zero_ or more chars. It finds _zero_ digits in the beginning of the string, and returns them. You can test this by trying the same regex on string `"34_person"`, `/[0-9]*/` will return both digits.

Comment: Its not being greedy, its being lazy!  Thanks to both.